# Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. while using formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, formik

```
import React, { useCallback, useMemo, useRef, useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { CustomInputField, CustomToggleButton, CustomControlLabel, CustomForm } from "@Custom/Custom-ui";
import { convertNameToHumanRedable } from "app/components/common/editor/control-resource-resolver";
import { Box } from "@material-ui/core";
import _ from "underscore";

const formatDropdownData = dataToFormat => {
    if (typeof dataToFormat === "string") {
        return { label: dataToFormat, value: dataToFormat };
    }
    return dataToFormat;
};

function FormBuilder(props) {
    const { data, onChange } = props;
    const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(true);
    const prevValues = useRef();
    const ref = useRef();

    const formRef = React.useCallback(node => {
        if (node) {
            ref.current = node;
            setIsValid(node.isValid);
            if (node.values && node.values !== prevValues.current) {
                prevValues.current = node.values;
                onChange(node.values);
            }
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);
    const initialValues = useMemo(() => {
        const values = {};
        data.forEach(({ name, defaultValue, type }) => {
            if (type === "select" && typeof defaultValue === "string") {
                values[name] = {
                    label: defaultValue,
                    value: defaultValue
                };
            } else {
                values[name] = defaultValue;
            }
        });
        return values;
    }, [data]);
    const getUIControls = useCallback(fielddata => {
        var { type, name, label, placeholder, defaultValue, options } = fielddata;
        label = label ?? convertNameToHumanRedable(name);
        switch (type) {
            case "string":
            case "password":
            case "number":
                return (
                    <CustomInputField
                        label={label}
                        type="string"
                        name={name}
                        key={type}
                        fullWidth={true}
                        placeholder={placeholder}
                        isFormElement={true}
                    />
                );
            case "boolean":
                return (
                    <CustomControlLabel
                        key={name}
                        label={label}
                        control={<CustomToggleButton name={name} isFormElement={true} />}
                    />
                );
            case "select": {
                let formattedData = [];
                options.forEach(data => {
                    formattedData.push(formatDropdownData(data));
                });
                return (
                    <CustomInputField
                        label={label}
                        name={name}
                        key={name}
                        placeholder={placeholder}
                        select
                        SelectProps={{
                            options: formattedData
                        }}
                        isFormElement
                        defaultValue={formatDropdownData(defaultValue)}
                    />
                );
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }, []);

    const getInputFields = useCallback(
        ({ values, setFieldValue }) => {
            return data.map(fielddata => {
                var { visibility, name, defaultValue } = fielddata;
                let visible = true;
                if (visibility) {
                    let template = _.template(visibility);
                    let templatizedString = template({ properties: values });
                    visible = eval(templatizedString);
                }
                if (visible) {
                    setFieldValue(name, defaultValue);
                }

                return (
                    <Box key={name} hidden={!visible}>
                        {getUIControls(fielddata)}
                    </Box>
                );
            });
        },
        [data]
    );

    return (
        <CustomForm
            values={initialValues}
            // validationSchema={validationSchema}
            formRef={formRef}
            validateOnMount={true}
            validateOnBlur={true}
        >
            {formikProps => getInputFields(formikProps)}
        </CustomForm>
    );
}

export default FormBuilder;

FormBuilder.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.arrayOf(
        PropTypes.shape({
            name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            placeholder: PropTypes.string,
            defaultValue: PropTypes.string,
            required: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
            label: PropTypes.string
        })
    ).isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func
};
```

It throws an error

```
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

after adding this

```
if (visible) {
   setFieldValue(name, defaultValue);
}
```

inside getInputFields.
I know this occurs since I am setting the state and it in turns re-renders the component which results in a infinite loop.

I want to set the value of the field to default value if its visibility is false.

This is a form-builder component which in takes an array of object as input and returns a form component.Am I doing the right thing? Or is there any other good approach.

Thanks in advance for spending your time to check this.